# Stack Overflow-like site for sysadmins

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Sorry for the silly question, but could somebody recommend a site like Stack Overflow for UNIX sysadmins?

Comment: There is a sysadmin site called http://serverfault.com/. Not uniquely for unix, but there are unix questions there as well.

Comment: If you scroll to the bottom of any page, there's a list of sister sites too. Including Server Fault, Super User, API/Apps, and more.

Answer (score 13):

As Fredrik Mörk said in a comment, the "sysadmin Stack Overflow" is called [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/).

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried looking at the other StackExchange sites e.g. http://unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: For Sysadmins, I'd say ServerFault is better.

Answer (score -7):

Have you tried [www.superuser.com](http://www.superuser.com)?

Comment: Super User is for personal computers, not System administrators.